# How to write a policy that allows either claim

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have the following 2 policies. In my logic I need to check if either one of these policies apply.

```
options.AddPolicy("ADD", policy =>
    policy.RequireClaim("Addition", "add"));

options.AddPolicy("SUB", policy =>
    policy.RequireClaim("Substraction", "subs"));
```

For example, If policy `ADD` or `SUB` is present then allow it to access the method. How can I get this to work ?

**Approaches I tried**:

I looked into the following approach. I wrote a new policy that allows both `ADD` or `SUB` to it.

```
options.AddPolicy("ADDSUB", policy =>
    policy.RequireClaim("Addition", "add")
    .RequireClaim("Substraction", "sub"));
```

Applied on the method as :

```
[Authorize(Policy = "ADDSUB")]
 [HttpPost]
 public IActionResult PerformCalculation()
 {
 }
```

However, this did not work. I think this a AND operation. What I need is a OR operation, where it'll allow either ADD or SUB in.

Answer (score 2):

See ["Using a func to fulfill a policy"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-2.1#using-a-func-to-fulfill-a-policy) on MS Docs. You can use the `RequireAssertion` policy builder to perform the necessary logic (e.g. belonging to either two claim types which is what you're after) by supplying it a `Func<AuthorizationHandlerContext, bool>`.

For example:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("ADDSUB", policy =>
        policy.RequireAssertion(context =>
            context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "Addition" && c.Value == "add") || 
            context.User.HasClaim(c => c.Type == "Substraction" && c.Value == "subs")));
});
```

Comment: While this does attempt to answer the question, it would have been better if it wasn't a dumb copy-paste.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto the link to the documentation and sample snippet seemed to provide adequate information to provide a solution to the problem of the question. I've updated the answer based on your feedback.

Comment: Sorry but I don't get what `ClaimTypes.BadgeId ` and `ClaimTypes.TemporaryBadgeId`. Can you explain

Comment: @sharonHwk I've edited the sample to reflect what you should be looking for. That's what I mean by a more meaningful answer